# How can I alternate texts in repeat for one textview using vertical translation?

Tags: android, user-interface, animation, android-animation

I am trying to alternate three different texts for one textview. I want to use vertical translation, where text appears from bottom to top and keeps repeating this animation. With the current code I have, I keep running into a problem where the the textview is translated all the way vertically up to the parent layout top. I only want the animation to happen within the height of the textView. Any advice will be much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

I created a custom animation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="-100%p"
        android:duration="3000"
        android:repeatCount="0"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        />
</set>
```

```
val linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout)
val textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)

val animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.ex1)

animation.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
    override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation) {}

    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation) {
        if (textView.text == "First Text") {
            textView.text = "Second Text"
        } else {
            textView.text = "First Text"
        }
        linearLayout.startAnimation(animation)
    }

    override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation) {}
})

linearLayout.startAnimation(animation)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are applying the animation on LinearLayout. Instead, apply the animation on TextView.

```
textView.startAnimation(animation)
```

Also, if you share the xml layout, we can understand the problem better.